# Is JSON same with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have tried to run following code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(result);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
jsonResponse.put("sEcho", echo);
jsonResponse.put("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
jsonResponse.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", iFilteredTotalRecords);
jsonResponse.put("aaData", json);
jsonResponse.toString();

JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
for (Object obj : result) {
    JSONArray row = new JSONArray();
    User user = (User) obj;
    row.put(user.getId()).put(user.getUserName()).put(user.isEnabled());
    data.put(row);
}
JSONObject jsonResponse2 = new JSONObject();
jsonResponse2.put("sEcho", echo);
jsonResponse2.put("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
jsonResponse2.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", iFilteredTotalRecords);
jsonResponse2.put("aaData", data);
jsonResponse2.toString();
```

The result from toString function for both jsonResponse are as follows:

```
{"iTotalDisplayRecords":11,"iTotalRecords":11,"aaData":"[{\"creationTime\":0,\"enabled\":true,\"id\":1,\"loginDuration\":0,\"online\":false,\"password\":\"asda\",\"userName\":\"abiieez\"}]","sEcho":"1"}

{"iTotalDisplayRecords":11,"iTotalRecords":11,"aaData":[[1,"abiieez",true]],"sEcho":"1"}
```

I would like to eliminate the " symbol before [ and after ] from the first json response just like the second one (I noticed that the " is added after the array being put to the jsonResponse object). How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you first convert your "result" to a String, and then add it to aaData, it will end up quoted, like a String should. If all you'd like to do is to remove the quotes, you could do something like this in line 2:

```
String json = "##" + gson.toJson(result) + "##";
```

and this in line 8:

```
jsonResponse.toString().replace("\"##", "").replace("##\"","");
```

(of course you need to choose the "quote marker" ## such that it will never appear as actual string content in your data anywhere else)

But the cleaner solution (although probably slower) would likely be to convert your String to an actual JSONObject by changing line 2 to:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(result));
```